# Display Pdf file in browser using Servlet

Tags: java, pdf, servlets

I am using intellij Idea and I have saved my pdf file in resources folder. I want to display that pdf file in browser.

```
public class GetDocumentation extends HttpServlet {
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GetDocumentation.class);
@Override
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    InputStream pdf_path = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(ApplicationProperties.getProperty("PDF_PATH"));

    resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
    resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Documentation.pdf");
    OutputStream responseOutputStream = resp.getOutputStream();

    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
    int len = -1;

    while ((len = pdf_path.read(buf)) != -1) {
      responseOutputStream.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    responseOutputStream.flush();
    responseOutputStream.close();
  }
}


<a href="/documentation">Documentation</a>
```

I am using Jsp servlet and I am calling "/documentation". And my file is getting rendered but it's blank. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: As you set the Content-Desposition header, the file should not be displayed inside browser. The browser should display a open/save dialogue. Are you sure your server side code finds the file and sends it in response? You don't have any exception on server side?

Answer (score 0):

`inline` Content-Disposition should be used to display the document. Replace `"attachment"` with `"inline"`:

```
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Documentation.pdf");
```